# How to slide div down and reveal hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a hidden div under header and want it to appear by sliding down on user click. But, i cannot achieve sliding effect even if my code appears to be right. Can you help me to find out what is a problem? I believe problem is in this:

```
#logRegFormContainer{
    display: none;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 980px;
    min-height: 80px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}
```

[JSfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9R9DV/)

Comment: remove the min-height property

Comment: @APAD1 it helps, but when i add some elements inside of that container , white space appers on top while animation is proceed, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of `min-height` in the CSS (though I'm unsure as to *why* `min-height` causes this problem); if this is replaced by `height` then it works: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9R9DV/1/).

Comment: I think because it will try to keep that hight, but because the function slide''(this will try to edit the hight) tries to do this it will only 'Hide' and 'Show'. @DavidThomas

Comment: Yes, now slide effect works fine, but when i add some elements inside of `#logRegFormContainer` there appears white space while animation is in procced, why?

Comment: @Amal.A: does it, what did you add? For me [it doesn't seem to happen](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9R9DV/3/).

Comment: @DavidThomas there is a bunch of another containers, which contain `<ul>` elements, buttons, inputs and etc, do you know why this white space could appear, btw thank you sir.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you're working with? Or at least offer an updated demo of your code to demonstrate what's going on, because I'm not really able to offer speculation on the reason without seeing something.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `min-height` property.

This will prevent the div from being any height less than 80px, and therefore prevent slide animation.